# is there a xaml editor for xamarin on visual studio community edition?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I am investigating xamarin forms for windows phone development and I'm trying to work with an example project from the following book:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/4/7/747DDA87-CA9F-4394-9B3F-4426BFE52BBF/Microsoft_Press_eBook_Xamarin_Preview_2_PDF.pdf

I got it to compile fine on the local machine, so far so good. When I try to open the xaml file for the app layout in the visual editor I get the following message:

[image]

I'm using visual studio community edition 2015

My question is: is there a visual editor for xaml I can use and how can I acquire it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. Xamarin might be working on it for a long while but they never clearly announce such a plan.

Microsoft instead offers IntelliSense if you are editing Xamarin.Forms XAML in the code editor as it once announced.